# Why is no compile-time error when calling an ambiguous ctor?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, ambiguous, overload-resolution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto v1 = std::vector<std::size_t>(std::size_t{8});
    std::cout << v1.size() << std::endl;

    auto v2 = std::vector<std::size_t>{std::size_t{8}};
    std::cout << v2.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The code outputs:

```
8
1
```

I know this is a well-known problem in C++ because of:

`std::vector<std::size_t>(std::size_t{8})` calls

`explicit vector(size_type count)` while

`std::vector<std::size_t>{std::size_t{8}}` calls

`vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())`.

To my surprise:

**Why does the second call not trigger a compile-time error for overload resolution ambiguity?**

[In another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507602/why-does-the-number-of-elements-in-a-initializer-list-cause-an-ambiguous-call-er), a piece of similar code does trigger an ambiguity error.

Comment: The use of curly-brackets `{}` makes it non-ambiguous. It will always use a `std::initializer_list` constructor if one is available.

Comment: Why does this one trigger an ambiguity error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507602/why-does-the-number-of-elements-in-a-initializer-list-cause-an-ambiguous-call-er

Comment: The initializer_list has higher priority if the types match

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is no ambiguity that can cause an error. Overload resolution is explicitly different when we use list initialization. It's done intentionally in two phases.

> **[over.match.list]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.match.list#1) When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized
>   ([dcl.init.list]), overload resolution selects the constructor in two
>   phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T and the argument list
>     consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
>     elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default
>   constructor, the first phase is omitted. In copy-list-initialization,
>   if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is
>   ill-formed. [ Note: This differs from other situations
>   ([over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy]), where only converting
>   constructors are considered for copy-initialization. This restriction
>   only applies if this initialization is part of the final result of
>   overload resolution.  — end note ]

In the first step **only** `std::initializer_list` constructors are considered. And we can reach the second step where other constructors are considered only if the first overload resolution failed. Obviously overload resolution does not fail to find an appropriate `std::initializer_list` constructor.

The question you link to is not about ambiguity in initializing vectors. The ambiguity is in choosing a function overload. Both are viable because both accept a different vector that can be itself initialized *unambiguously* from the same initializer list.