# Why does initalizer syntax with two elements put one element to a vector of strings instead of two?

Tags: c++, string, vector, list-initialization

Why do I get one element in `b` instead of two? In `a` I get one as expected and in `c` three elements as expected. The one with the two values is somehow a special case.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print(const std::string& name, const std::vector<std::string>& v)
{
    std::cout << name << ' ' << v.size() << '\n';
    for (const auto& str : v) {
        std::cout << str << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> a = {{"str1"}};
    std::vector<std::string> b = {{"str1", "str2"}};
    std::vector<std::string> c = {{"str1", "str2", "str3"}};
    print("a", a);
    print("b", b);
    print("c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
a 1
str1

b 1
str1

c 3
str1
str2
str3
```

I guess it has something to do with this overload of the vector ctor.

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

I used clang 9.0.0 with `-std=c++17 -O2 -Wall` as flags.

What did the compiler do in the case of `b`? Why did it decide it's an iterator in one case and initializer list in the other cases? Is my sample code well defined or does it have UB?

Comment: Similar to [Why does the number of elements in a initializer list cause an ambiguous call error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507602/why-does-the-number-of-elements-in-a-initializer-list-cause-an-ambiguous-call-er/41507731#41507731).

Comment: Replacing `{{...}}` with `{...}` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my sample code well defined or does it have UB?

It does have UB. The constructor that takes the `first`-`last` iterator pair presumes that both iterators refer to the same sequence. `{{"str1"}, {"str2"}}` does not fulfill this requirement, hence UB.

> What did the compiler do in the case of `b`? Why did it decide it's an iterator in one case and initializer list in the other cases?

Recall that a string literal "str1" is of type `char const[5]`. However, calls to the constructor overload for `std::initializer_list` work with `std::string` instances. This requires an implicit conversion - and as the constructor template for two iterators doesn't require such a conversion, it's considered a better match.

---

You can fix this by forcing direct list-initialization with one pair of braces,

```
std::vector<std::string> b2 = {"str1", "str2"};
```

or by manually specifying the desired type at least once:

```
std::vector<std::string> b3 = {{std::string("str1"), "str2"}};

using namespace std::string_literals;
std::vector<std::string> b4 = {{"str1"s, "str2"s}};
```